# IBM Bluemix Application Security on Cloud Service

Tags: ibm-cloud, bluemix-app-scan

I'm wanting to test out IBM's Application Security on Cloud for Bluemix on a dynamic web app.

The issue I'm having is that after I declare that a login is required, the only fields to fill in are username & password with the option of a third credential.

I'm wondering if there's a possibility to define the fields and associated values as different ways to login? For example: a username, PIN and DoB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was already raised as a [RFE](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=85696) by another user and is definitely a capability that we want to add. 
We are experimenting with different ideas on how to allow the users to define extra fields that are needed for the login.

Regards,
Eitan